# "Holding out for a hero" - is this song about sex?

Tags: meaning, pop

Whenever I listen to this song, I always picture the singer lying in bed waiting for her man to come home and have sex with her, so many of the lyrics seem to have a double meaning.

Is it just my imagination, or is this intentional?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of mild sexual [innuendo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innuendo) is fairly typical for pop songs... no reason to think you're imagining it!

The singer is not waiting for a particular man, though - she's just hoping that someone suitable will turn up. Or at least, that's what she's imagining...